# how to use if else on the laravel controller and display alert

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

> if will display successfully added data
>   else the data entered is incorrect
>   [image]

```
public function store_perorangan(Request $request)
    {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'img_pengalaman' => 'required|file|max:2000',
        'img_npwp' => 'required|file|max:2000',
        'img_pph' => 'required|file|max:2000',
        'img_keahlian' => 'required|file|max:2000',
        'img_domisili' => 'required|file|max:2000',
        'img_ktp' => 'required|file|max:2000',
        'img_no_rek' => 'required|file|max:2000',
        ]);

    if return redirect ('/profile')->with('alert-success','Berhasil Menambahkan Data!');    {

    }
    else{
        return redirect ('/profile')->with('alert','Data yang anda masukkan lebih dari 2mb !');
    }
}
```

> please help me

My profile blade:

```html
if(\Session::has('alert'))
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
 <div>{{Session::get('alert')}}
 </div> 
 </div> 
endif 
if(\Session::has('alert-success')) 
<div class="alert alert-success"> <div>{{Session::get('alert-success')}}</div> 
</div> 
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This is php's if statement, you lost the condition.

See the [php-doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

```php
   if ($data->save()) {
        return redirect('/profile')->with('alert-success','Berhasil Menambahkan Data!'); 
   } else {
        return redirect('/profile')->with('alert','Data yang anda masukkan lebih dari 2mb !');
   }
```

Since you are using Laravel 5.8, Laravel 5.8+ use [session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) **helper method** instead of **session class** in blade.
So you need to display the alert like this:

```php
@if (session('alert-success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('alert-success') }}
    </div>
@endif
@if (session('alert'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session('alert') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: alert does not appear (return redirect('/profile')->with('alert','Data yang anda masukkan lebih dari 2mb !');)

Comment: maybe you can add your html code since thats where the alert going to show right?

Comment: @yooyo yes. u need to check your html.Here is doc about how to [display-alert](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data).

Comment: if(\Session::has('alert'))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <div>{{Session::get('alert')}}</div>
                            </div>
                            endif
                            if(\Session::has('alert-success'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                <div>{{Session::get('alert-success')}}</div>
                            </div>
                            endif

Comment: @yooyo What's your laravel version?

Comment: Follow the doc I have post, Laravel 5.8+ use `session()` helper method instead of `\Session` class. And I have post it to the answer.

Comment: still not appearing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206331/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-yooyo).